# matplotlib mathtext can't find fonts

Tags: python, fonts, matplotlib

I'm trying to figure out how to get mathtext working in python matplotlib.

They provide some [small example code](http://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html#mathtext-tutorial) which I have reproduced below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)

plt.plot(t,s)
plt.title(r'$\alpha_i > \beta_i$', fontsize=20)
plt.text(1, -0.6, r'$\sum_{i=0}^\infty x_i$', fontsize=20)
plt.text(0.6, 0.6, r'$\mathcal{A}\mathrm{sin}(2 \omega t)$',
     fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.ylabel('volts (mV)')
plt.show()
```

When I try and run this code, I get lots of warnings that look like this:
`/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1242: UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['cmtt10'] not found. Falling back to Bitstream Vera Sans
  (prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))`

and the mathtext doesn't render correctly. The figure looks like this:

[image: Figure with broken fonts]

When it should look like this:

[image: how figure should look]

Comment: try clearing matplotlib'd font cache

Comment: what's your system and versions of python and matplotlib you're using?

Comment: @DavidZwicker fedora 14, python 2.7, python-matplotlib-1.0.1-12.fc14.i686

Comment: @PaulH tried removing fontList.cache, but it didn't help

Comment: Dang. That often fixes a lot these problems. Can you try updating matplotlib to the current version (1.2)?

Comment: @PaulH It's broken in the latest version in my fedora repository, but I downloaded the latest tar and installed all the dependencies with yum and built v1.2 from source. That fixed the problem.

Comment: I don't know what the right protocol is on stackoverflow, for a question that's essentially answered in comments.

Comment: @Joe you should answer your question and mark it as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was a bug with an older version of matplotlib, the version that was in my fedora repository. I downloaded and installed the latest version, and this fixed the bug.

To get the latest version, I had to build it from source. Following the instructions from the matplotlib [installation instructions page](http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html),

First, get the build dependencies:
`sudo yum-builddep python-matplotlib`

Then, from the [download page](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/downloads) get the latest .tar.gz (version 1.2 at time of writing)

Then, the rest is taken care of by a python install script.

```
cd matplotlib // wherever the .tar.gz was extracted to.
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```